# How to pass radio button for selected value to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button, strong-typing

I have a strongly typed radio button in MVC. How to save the value to the model property

```
<ul class="formlist">
    <li class="width100">
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model._Account[i].account_flag, 1, new { @id = Model._Service[i].service_id, @Name = "text" + @Model._Service[i].service_id, @checked = "false" })<span>Yes</span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
            <label class="form-check-label">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model._Account[i].account_flag, 0, new { @id = Model._Service[i].service_id, @Name = "text" + @Model._Service[i].service_id, @checked = "checked" })<span>No</span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine for me. Hope this would be useful.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "my_form" }))
{
<ul class="formlist">
  <li class="width100">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model._Account[i].account_flag, 1, new { id = Model._Service[i].service_id, Name = "text" + @Model._Service[i].service_id, @checked = "false" })<span>Yes</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model._Account[i].account_flag, 0, new { id = Model._Service[i].service_id, Name = "text" + @Model._Service[i].service_id, @checked = "checked" })<span>No</span>
      </label>
    </div>
</li>
```

}

Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

  namespace sample_project.Models
  {
    public class SampleModel
    {
        public List<Account> _Account { get; set; }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public string account_flag { get; set; }
        public int service_id { get; set; }
    }
  }
```

Controller:

```
using sample_project.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace sample_project.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SampleModel model = new SampleModel();
            model._Account = new List<Account>();
            model._Account.Add(new Account() { service_id=1 });
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(SampleModel model)
        {
            string account_flag = model._Account[0].account_flag;

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: when posting to the controller, the account_flag property is still null

Comment: could you please share the get and post methods of the controller and model code